# Regularly copying files from Windows to Bash Ubuntu

Tags: bash

For my school work, I have to make sure that my programs compile on xterm (it's similar to bash).  I work in Visual Studio on Windows and regularly FTP my code to a school server to test it.  But, this is cumbersome because I have to log into FTP, upload the file, then use putty to connect to xterm on the school's server, and then compile and run the program.  I can't even keep the putty connection open for very long because it disconnects and/or freezes after a while (maybe 30 mins).

So, I prefer to use ubuntu bash in Windows.

Here is the information that I have found so far:

1- you do not want to ever open up the ubuntu bash files from Windows explorer.  Doing this can corrupt the files.
2- seems like reading the Windows files using vim is ok.
3- Microsoft seems to not support having one side (windows or bash) access files from the other side.

Here are my questions:

1- Is this the process that I should go through.  (1) close Visual Studio; (2) open up Ubuntu bash; (3) copy the appropriate visual studio files to a directory in the Ubuntu bash directories using Ubuntu bash commands; (4) compile the program

Or, instead of step 3, can I just compile the program using the g++ command and referencing the files in the Windows directory?

2- Is the process that I laid out in 1 a bad idea given that we are dealing here with the beta version of bash ubuntu and that moving files between the 2 systems is not really supported?  I suppose the alternative is to copy and paste the program from visual studio to vim.  Also, I am mostly a tech newbie, with just a basic understanding of Windows and OSX for day to day use.  I could do something that's less user error prone, like running a virtual machine (would upgrade my ram for that).  Do you think that would be a better plan?

3-  If I do copy files back and forth, I believe the command is cp /mnt/c/users/johnDoe/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/Project1/Project1/Source.cpp /~
So, in other words, the /~ will mean the main (top directory) in Ubuntu bash directory.  I believe this directory is located somewhere in apps data.  Does that command look correct (mainly questioning the /~ part)?

Comment: `xterm` is *nothing* like `bash`; it's a terminal emulator that serves as the "host" environment *in which* `bash` runs.

Comment: I stand corrected.  The school uses tcsh.  Thanks for pointing that out.